# Switching to a Standing Desk

Tags: environment, ergonomics

At work I have a standard desk (4 legs, flat surface, you get the picture).  For a while now I've been thinking about converting to a standing desk.  What would be the best way to go about this on a limited budget?  Are there some good laptop/keyboard stands I could place on my existing desk?  Which ones are the best?

I'm trying to avoid requesting a whole new desk, and keeping things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talk to an occupational therapist and get their advice because you'll be drastically changing the way you posture yourself for hours at a time.

Agencies that assist people with disabilities and their carers (if you're in Australia, look up the Independent Living Centre in your capital city) would be a good start. You'll be able to test out a variety of models if they have a showroom and get advice from a medical professional not a furniture salesman.

Answer (score 2):

This has been featured in a couple of blogs that are likely near and dear to most SOers:

- [Lifehacker: Coolest Workspace Contest: DIY Startup Desk](http://lifehacker.com/software/contest/coolest-workspace-contest--diy-startup-desk-170906.php)
- [Coding Horror: Computer Workstation Ergonomics](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000938.html)

I think there are clearly some benefits to standing for a portion of the day.  Even better would be a [treadmill desk](http://www.brainrules.net) (watch the "Exercise boosts brain power" film, and pay attention about 3:09 in).